# How to exclude all the test files except two using maven?

Tags: maven, include, maven-surefire-plugin

I like to do have something like bellow which will exclude all test cases except two of the test files?

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>path/to/Some1Test.java</include>
            <include>path/to/Some2Test.java</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Critical fact in here, the test files that I do not want to exclude, also has the same naming pattern as the files I want to exclude. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`excludes` wins on `includes` for the surefire plugin configuration (not documented but works in this way).   And it makes sense, since `excludes` should be seen as the exceptional case and `includes` as the general case : you geneally want to include all but .....

But here you want to exactly the reverse.
So don't mix both elements because with your actual conf :

```
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <includes>
        <include>path/to/Some1Test.java</include>
        <include>path/to/Some2Test.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
```

you exclude all since`excludes` excludes all here(`<exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>`) and that `excludes` win on `includes`.

All you need is to define `includes` only to make only these tests executed :

```
  <configuration>      
    <includes>
        <include>path/to/Some1Test.java</include>
        <include>path/to/Some2Test.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is the solution with an example:

```
package com.example1;
import org.junit.Test;
public class TestClass1 {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
    }
}


package com.example1;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestClass2 {
    @Test
    public void test2() {
    }
}

package com.example2;
import org.junit.Test;
public class TestClass1 {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
    }
}

package com.example2;
import org.junit.Test;
public class TestClass2 {
    @Test
    public void test2() {
    }
}
```

Now, following is the surefire plugin configuration for inclusion of `com.example1.TestClass1` and `com.example1.TestClass2`. Here, other test classes will not be executed except these two.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com/example1/TestClass1.java</include>
                        <include>com/example1/TestClass2.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The solution has a problem. for example, I have 100 classes. From them I want to exclude certain classes, and include other classes. Using your solution I have to include or exclude manually them. This is not as expected. Rather if I have specify certain patters of exclusion or inclusion, work will much easier

Comment: Your point is valid and can be implemented by using regex for exclusion and inclusion of Test Classes. Maven surefire provides this capability. Please refer following link: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html